# Why are we not using function databases instead of packages/libraries?

Tags: ide, programming-languages, language-design

Why are not we using, instead of the actual packages/libraries concepts, a centralized function database? I can see many advantages.

1. Easier to grow (anyone could send his small functions, as oposed to the work necessary to sustain a big
2. Analyzable. Statisticals and graph theory tools could be used to analyze and categorize the database.
3. Ultimate productivity tool. Suppose you have the task of converting all images in a folder to black-and-white. You could google to search and install image manipulation and os packages for your language, then study then and search for the right functions. The whole process could take a day. Or you could search for an "open images files in a folder" function, a "convert images to black/white" function, and a "save image" function on said global database, and the whole process could take a minute. **Now generalize this to any programming task and you can figure out why I find this so important.**

Why is this concept not adopted?

Comment: How is that different from a package manager?

Comment: The difference is that you add the overhead of learning aspects of a big package when all you need is that small function.

Comment: Also there are many small functions that you won't find in big packages, yet are essential on a daily basis and you end up making yourself. Example: need to convert a string to mixed case. You could spend minutes programming it, hours googling for that function (doubt you'll find), or easily search on a function database.

Comment: Still, when you search in your big library, you need to learn how the functions work. As a side note, what would you do with name clashes? Link time is also a huge issue. And what would you do with incompatibilities between libraries?

Comment: This seems like the germ of a cool idea, but dependencies and versioning are the flies in the ointment. Once you solve those problems, you might be left with something very similar to a package manager.

Comment: What you are asking is basically a library containing all the libraries there is and ever will be. Seems like a HUGE database on its own. Most probably none of our computers could handle a search in that library.

Comment: Shahbaz this is absolutely not true, at all. Why do you think so? I'm sure a database could grow up to millions of categorized/tagged/analyzed functions in my local computer without breaking it.

Comment: Borderline (?) off-topic.  Perhaps suited to PSE?

Comment: I don't think it's really off-topic that way -- what bothers me more is some inflammatory wording.  Maybe the question could be edited to improve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an interesting idea.  I think the crux of the matter is this: a well-designed library (or set of libraries) is *coherent*, in that it carefully chooses a small set of functions, datastructures, and other conventions.  This is what lets programmers understand, use, and reuse it.

A massive function database seems like an attempt to make an incoherent, undesigned mass of functions reusable in the same sense.  But I don't think the hard part of the problem is finding relevant functions in the first place:  I'm afraid it's the sheer combinatorial explosion of arbitrary technical choices (inherent even in moderately simple tasks) that will defeat most attempts at direct reuse (as opposed to pseudocode-like inspiration).

Take your "open images in a folder" example query, and consider how a possible target function might:

- identify the folder: directory handle, string, or one of a dozen "path" datastructures
- choose a particular image: string, pattern match, or one of many interactive UI options
- handle image formats: e.g., GIF, JPG, PNG, or a variety of polyglot image loader frameworks
- load the image: unconditionally, header/metadata then body, by tile, by row, or something else
- represent the image: what datastructure does it use to store the loaded image?
- use exceptions, errors, or intermediate decision points

Some of these possibilities can be readily handled by the programmer (assuming the function is properly documented).  Some may be patchable (e.g., by finding another function to translate from the framebuffer format provided to one you can use).  But others have heavyweight technical implications.  An interactive UI file chooser will require the use of a particular UI framework.  A polyglot image loader function can pull in dozens of image libraries, and commit you to its memory management scheme.

To put it another way: "design for reuse" has been the hopeful motto of the software engineer for decades, and our best efforts have met with only modest success.  However, long experience has taught us the lesson implicit in the motto: without the "design" part, "reuse" doesn't stand a chance.